# Question bad closed What do I do?

Tags: support

A few days ago I closed the question 
"Ubuntu-SDK-Ide 4.10 (Zesty zapus) “No storage pool found” [closed]
When trying to create a new kit, i receive the following error message "error: No storage pool found. Please create a new storage pool. ---Task exited with errors, please check the output---" Is there any way to solve it?"

Based on:
**"This question is specific to **an end of life Ubuntu release**. These are no longer supported and are therefore off-topic here. To upgrade, see: How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?" – mikewhatever, karel"**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/894362/ubuntu-sdk-ide-4-10-zesty-zapus-no-storage-pool-found

This is a reading error of those who closed it since it does not refer to Ubuntu 4.10. The question is about Ubuntu-Sdk-Ide, the 4.10 being its last version https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/tools-development

Answer (score 5):

i've edited your question to provide the clarifications.

However, Zesty Zapus support here is still limited until it is fully released.  Assuming you don't get the error in non-Zesty, then it is a bug in that package or a dependency that might need reported on Launchpad, and would still be offtopic because it is then a bug report or a bug that needs reported.

So I am not going to change the "closed" status given that reasoning.

Comment: Maybe you could change it from off-topic #3 to off-topic #2? Might make it a little clearer

Comment: @Zanna done by Seth.